# How do I change the default tooltip when dragging an external image into a div?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, tooltip

I am uploading images by dragging them from my disk and dropping them onto a `div`. This bit is accomplished.

What I want to do is to somehow configure the default tooltip that gets shown when the dragged image is on the drop area.

To be more specific, I'd like to replace `Move` with my own text:

[image: To be more specific, I'd like to replace 'move' with my own text]

Any pointers on how to accomplish this using plain JavaScript (or otherwise) or even if it is possible would be great.

Here's my JavaScript code. At some point I am injecting this element into the `DOM`. To reiterate, this functionality works fine, it's just that I want to change the default text in tooltip which shows up when I have dragged an image onto this element (as shown in the image above).

```
var imageHolderDiv = UWA.createElement('div', {
  'id': 'uploadImageButton',
  'class': 'uploadImageButton',
  'styles': {
    'width': '104px',
    'height': '104px',
    'vertical-align': 'top'
  },
  'events': {
    dragenter: function(event) {
      counter++;
      imageHolderDiv.classList.remove('uploadImageButton');
      imageHolderDiv.classList.add('somethingIsDraggedOverMe');
    }.bind(this),

    dragleave: function(event) {
      counter--;
      if (counter == 0) {
        imageHolderDiv.classList.remove('somethingIsDraggedOverMe');
        imageHolderDiv.classList.add('uploadImageButton');
      }
    }.bind(this),

    dragover: function(event) {
      imageHolderDiv.classList.add('somethingIsDraggedOverMe');
      //kill any default behavior
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
    }.bind(this),

    drop: function(event) {
      //kill any default behavior
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();

      imageHolderDiv.classList.remove('somethingIsDraggedOverMe');
      imageHolderDiv.classList.add('uploadImageButton');

      var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
      var that = this;
      if (file && file.type.match('image.*')) {
        MyWebServices.uploadImage({
            file: file,
            fileName: file.name
            onComplete: function(res, args) {},
            onFailure: function() {}
          );
        }
        else {
          //if its not an image
        }
      }.bind(this)
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the reason for downvote? its a genuine question. If you need information please let me know instead of anonymous downvotes for no apparent reason

Comment: What is the code that you have? Can you post your working example on which you need assistance with? This is a very vague/open-ended question with multiple possibilities on what could go wrong or what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: @Rikin Added code if it helps.

Comment: Atleast that tells me that you are trying to create element and wire up your code using a utility. With that, can you post which utility you are trying along with which plugin. Your issue is probably with its default values/behavior

Comment: @Rikin btw same behavior is also observed on other services like google drive when you drag an external file into browser, the 'Move' tooltip is displayed on hover over droppable area. This doesn't seem to be an issue with my specific code or framework and looks like a generic behavior which may or may not be configurable (I sure hope it is configurable somehow).